# Limiting CSS framework to Vue scope

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I got a problem with the tailwind preflight. It's resetting some styles globally, which I really don't want it to. And disabling preflight would be a huge amount of work.

So, is there a way to use a css famework just inside the Vue.js scope without it affecting other styles of the page (I'm using Vue on top of an existing project)?

Importing it as usual:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import ImportConfig from "~/components/data_import/import_config/ImportConfig.vue";
import "~/styles/main.css";
```

Won't do the trick, cause the styles are accessible globally.

Also using VUe's custom-components ain't a proper solution cause these are using the shadow dom.

Comment: So basically you don't want every preflight styles from Tailwind in compiled CSS?

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka Exactly, I just want the preflight to take action inside the Vue part of the page. Using Vue custom-elements would do the trick - except for Vue usin the shadow dom then...

Comment: If you just remove `@tailwind base` from `main.css` file, it will remove preflight globally. Adding `@tailwind base` within scoped style of Vue may do the trick (but I don't know project architecture so no prediction here). My point is disabling preflights is not so hard and I'm not entirely sure you need all preflight styles in a scope (cause it styles body, table, hr, etc)

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka There even is a config for disabling the preflight in tailwind. But that's not an option cause I already build other features on top of that preflight. Including just the preflight css in scoped components also is an option I already tried, but that's just too much of a fiddling to work properly in production.